# Is there a way to configure use of a Proxy-Server in Servlet-configuration (web.xml)?

Tags: java, servlets, proxy

I have to write Servlets, that run on a server that forbids direct connections to the internet. But the servlets have to access other servers. Is there a possibility to configure a proxy per servlet?

I know, I can pass '-Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxyserver.com  -Dhttp.proxyPort=80' to the parameters for the JVM on Tomcat-startup. But I want a per servlet configuration of proxies. Is that possible, is there a way (maybe in the web.xml), or has it to be done by programming on each access to the internet?